# Account Association glitch

Tags: support

I appear to have had some form of account association glitch.

I was perusing meta and got presented with a "Welcome to" top-hat. I entered my openid credentials and have ended up with a new account, when I should be logged in as `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7872/rob`.

This is the second time I've had a "weird thing" happen with my account/account associations (the last time was, I think, with superuser). Is it something to do with me "self hosting" my OpenId on `robertwray.co.uk`? Either way, can I:

1. Get the two accounts merged
2. Get a canonical answer as to what I'm doing wrong that's caused this, and how to make sure it doesn't happen? =)

> **Note:** I'm well aware that it's almost certainly something I'm doing wrong, but I'd quite like to know what that is so I can stop doing it! :)

**More importantly: How can I login as my other (primary) account, as I'd really rather use that one rather than this one that has no rep, etc,...**

Comment: +1 for confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your openids is through AOL, the other is through your blog. They are two different OpenIDs. I merged the accounts.